# In Phonegap/Cordova 3.0+, is there any way to refresh plugins after you make changes?

Tags: cordova

Sorry guys if this is a simple question, which I'm hoping it is. The PhoneGap/Cordova documentation is pretty bad.

So with the directory structure:

```
/platforms/
   /ios/
   /android/
/plugins/
/www/
```

Is there anyway to make changes in the parent plugin directory and then have it apply those changes to the different platforms? I'm doing:

```
cordova prepare
```

This updates all the HTML from the parent `www` directory, but my plugins don't seem to get updated.

Hopefully someone can chime in with and give me a "doh!" moment.

Comment: I had the same issue when building a plugin. If you are modifying the plugin after installing, you edit the JS in the plugins/www location, but the platform specific code needs to be edited in the platform directories. I ended up creating a separate project where I did my plugin work and then when the plugin was ready to deploy I would install it on my actual project.

Answer (score 11):

I ran into the same issue. The only way I could consistently get my plugin to update would be to uninstall the plugin completely and reinstall it from scratch.

```
cordova plugin rm org.apache.cordova.plugin.example
cordova plugin add ../example-app-plugin/
```

In this example I am installing it from a local directory.

Comment: We're having this same problem. Wow. On iOS the plugins just work.

Answer (score 4):

I'm asking myself this question for a long time, and finally did a little script to make sure everything is up to date:

```
rm -rf -- platforms/*/
rm -rf platforms/platforms.json

rm -rf -- plugins/*/
rm -rf -- plugins/android.json
rm -rf -- plugins/ios.json
rm -rf -- plugins/fetch.json

cordova prepare
```

Have not found anything better yet

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
cordova plugin add ../example-app-plugin/ --link
```

This will work if you are not adding or removing files from your config.xml - in which case, rm/add seem to be the way to go. So if your file structure is pretty much settled, that should get the job done for you.

Answer (score 0):

All answers didn't work for me when using cordova@8 or higher, using a `file:` prefix seems to work:

```sh
cordova plugin add file:cordova-plugin-example
```